# PFQuery found a nonexistent object - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to query a nonexistent object like this code bellow, but always "Mike" is found. What could be wrong? Everything is working great (Save, Delete, Update and Query without error recognition).

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurant")
        query.whereKey("clientname", equalTo:"Mike")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
            print ("Found")
           } 

           else {
            print ("Not Found")
      }
    }
```

Comment: remove         query.whereKey("clientname", equalTo:"Mike") if you want all objects

Comment: Can't say anything unless you show your filtered data in browser. Run a filter in parse data browser to see if such an entry with clientname mike exists. If it does, then your question is invalid.

Comment: Mike really doesn't exist. I did this question because I think the NSError is not working very well in PFQuery. But @Handsomeguy gave a great solution bellow. Thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking (debugging) what "objects" actually is. I think you will see that it is an empty array, meaning it did NOT find Mike.

An empty array of results is not a query error. The query succeeds, but finds no objects. So not getting an error does not mean "Found". It just means there was no error.

Comment: It works great! Thank you! I had not thought this way. =)